# Kendo date range end date filtering

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Trying to set the end date to filter the kendo grid as well. Right now the user can filter between two dates but if the user just enters the end date I need to filter the grid. Here is the code I'm using not sure what I'm missing. My grid is similar to this one with the end date not working  http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/5bchz/86/

```
var orderDateFromFilter = $("#FromDate").val().split('-');
var orderDateToFilter = $("#ToDate").val().split('-');

if (orderDateFromFilter == "") {
    orderDateToFilter = "";
    $("#ToDate").val("");
    $("#input5").val("");
    $("#input6").val("");
}
else if (orderDateToFilter == "") {
    $("#ToDate").val($("#FromDate").val());
    $("#input6").val($("#input5").val());
    orderDateToFilter = orderDateFromFilter;
}

var mydate1 = new Date(orderDateFromFilter[0], orderDateFromFilter[1]-1, orderDateFromFilter[2]);
var mydate2 = new Date(orderDateToFilter[0], orderDateToFilter[1]-1, orderDateToFilter[2]);

var filter = { logic: "and", filters: [] };

    filter.filters.push({ field: "FilterByDate", operator: "gte", value: mydate1 });
    filter.filters.push({ field: "FilterByDate", operator: "lte", value: mydate2 });

    if (orderDateFromFilter== "" && orderDateToFilter == "")
        filter = "";
    grid.dataSource.filter(filter);
}
```

Comment: From the jsfiddle that you shared, within the "$("#datepicker, #datepicker1").on("change", function ()" function , change the "IF" conditions to "if (mindate)" and "if (maxdate)" and that will work for both filters if either one is selected.

Comment: As for your solution, change your "filter" variable to this to have logic as "or" -> "var filter = { logic: "or", filters: [] };"

Comment: deep206 Thanks it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this worked for me filter logic  "filter" variable to this to have logic as "or" -> "var filter = { logic: "or", filters: [] };"